# Using NSURLSession background task with WatchOS2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, apple-watch-complication

Wondering how we would use NSURLSession background task in watchOS 2.

I want to spawn a background download whenever complications wake up. What is not clear to me is where I would locate `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession`.

What part of WatchKit extension would wake up and where would I get this callback? This part is not very clear in documentation.

Comment: `- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context` in WKInterfaceController

Comment: It will wake the interfaceController? I doubt that. I have couple of interface controllers. In any case I am trying it out now so lets see if that works. Thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to spawn a background download whenever complications wake up.

If you're looking to asynchronously fetch data in your complication controller, you'll discover that [it is unreliable, as well as discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34712889/4151918).

To avoid unnecessarily exhausting your complication's execution time budget, you may want to consider letting your phone handle the background fetch, then using a `WCSession` instance to `transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo`.  This will send a high-priority message that will wake up your extension to deliver the data.

At that point, you either:

- wait for the complication controller's scheduled update to occur, or
- manually signal ClockKit to update your complication by calling `reloadTimelineForComplication` or `extendTimelineForComplication`.

You'll find specific details in the [watchOS 2 Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/CreatingaComplication.html), under **Updating Your Complication Data**.

## Different approaches for updating data:

- Explicit manual update via extension

  > When you have new data for your complication, you must use the reloadTimelineForComplication: or extendTimelineForComplication: method of the CLKComplicationServer object to signal to ClockKit that your complication is ready to be updated. ... Calling these methods causes ClockKit to create your data source object and request new data from it.
- Scheduled automatic update (using cached data) via complication controller `requestedUpdateDidBegin`

  > Scheduled updates are useful for apps whose data changes at predictable times. When a scheduled update occurs, ClockKit calls the requestedUpdateDidBegin or requestedUpdateBudgetExhausted method of your data source first. Use those methods to determine whether you have new data available.
- Push notification via `WKExtensionDelegate` `didReceiveRemoteNotification`
- Manual update via `WCSession` `transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo`

  > When your iOS app receives updated data intended for your complication, it can use the Watch Connectivity framework to update your complication right away. The transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo: method of WCSession sends a high priority message to your WatchKit extension, waking it up as needed to deliver the data. Upon receiving the data, extend or reload your timeline as needed to force ClockKit to request the new data from your data source.

Either way, the complication controller should merely use the new data available to it, instead of trying to (asynchronously) fetch any data it needs.

Comment: Hi Petah, Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Really appreciate it. I will be caching the complication data anyways from watch app or phone app, but the client requirement is for complication to work independently as well, so the data download part is only for that. In any case, if you go through the WWDC session of complications, they mention clearly we can use NSURLSession or Message passing through app, so currently I am implementing both. For NSURLSession, we will background task and wait for it to finish and cache it. Next requestedUpdateDidBegin we will show cached data and

Comment: start new download which will be used for next update. Its mostly weather information and hence requires frequent update. Thanks again for explaining the answer in details. :) :)